# How to get names of classes inside a jar file?

Tags: java, file, class, jar, classloader

I have a JAR file and I need to get the name of all classes inside this JAR file. How can I do that?

I googled it and saw something about JarFile or Java `ClassLoader` but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Are you using some IDE?As it will be auto displayed if you are using one.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, but I need to do this with code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - The potential duplicate has answers with examples as well as resources for documentation. Searching for one of those class names + example will yield several useful results.

Comment: @Alias the possible duplicate states how to find and get a file from a jar, while the question is about getting the class names inside a jar (possibly the classes in all packages inside it). The link in ErikKaju's answer points to a possible solution using `JarInputStream` and `JarEntry` classes that I can't find in any answer of your referred link.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Unfortunately, Java doesn't provide an easy way to list classes in the "native" JRE. That leaves you with a couple of options: (a) for any given JAR file, you can list the entries inside that JAR file, find the `.class` files, and then determine which Java class each `.class` file represents; or (b) you can use a library that does this for you.

### Option (a): Scanning JAR files manually

In this option, we'll fill `classNames` with the list of all Java classes contained inside a jar file at `/path/to/jar/file.jar`.

```
List<String> classNames = new ArrayList<String>();
ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("/path/to/jar/file.jar"));
for (ZipEntry entry = zip.getNextEntry(); entry != null; entry = zip.getNextEntry()) {
    if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
        // This ZipEntry represents a class. Now, what class does it represent?
        String className = entry.getName().replace('/', '.'); // including ".class"
        classNames.add(className.substring(0, className.length() - ".class".length()));
    }
}
```

### Option (b): Using specialized reflections libraries

#### Guava

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) has had [`ClassPath`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/14.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html) since at least 14.0, which I have used and liked. One nice thing about `ClassPath` is that it doesn't load the classes it finds, which is important when you're scanning for a large number of classes.

```
ClassPath cp=ClassPath.from(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
for(ClassPath.ClassInfo info : cp.getTopLevelClassesRecurusive("my.package.name")) {
    // Do stuff with classes here...
}
```

#### Reflections

I haven't personally used [the Reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections), but it seems well-liked. Some great examples are provided on the website like this quick way to load all the classes in a package provided by *any* JAR file, which may also be useful for your application.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");

Set<Class<? extends SomeType>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(SomeType.class);

Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(SomeAnnotation.class);
```

Comment: Reflections doesn't work if run from an executable jar either.

Comment: A Spring solution working from executable jars: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21430849/4265610.

Comment: Just use. jar tvf jarfile.jar. Why are you doing all this for.

Answer (score 255):

You can use Java `jar` tool. List the content of jar file in a txt file and you can see all the classes in the jar.

```shell
jar tvf jarfile.jar
```

> -t  list table of contents for archive
>
> -v  generate verbose output on standard output
>
> -f  specify archive file name

Comment: Thanks. This answers the "just get a class listing" part of the OP that wasn't asked.

Comment: You can also use `unzip -l jarfile.jar` in a pinch. A JAR file is just a zip file with a manifest!

Comment: The issue is that he likely wanted to get the class files inside a jar at runtime, given a classloader instance (likely to see what classes are loaded inside that specific jar).

Comment: This is great! And I found the office doc here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html

Comment: Also, this won't allow you to inspect annotations, which is likely something you'll want to do if you're scanning classes at runtime.

Answer (score 20):

Maybe you are looking for `jar` command to get the list of classes in terminal,

```
$ jar tf ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-assembly/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/spark-assembly-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-hadoop1.0.4.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
org/
org/apache/
org/apache/spark/
org/apache/spark/unused/
org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/org.spark-project.spark/
META-INF/maven/org.spark-project.spark/unused/
META-INF/maven/org.spark-project.spark/unused/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/org.spark-project.spark/unused/pom.properties
META-INF/NOTICE
```

where,

```
-t  list table of contents for archive
-f  specify archive file name
```

Or, just grep above result to see `.class`es only

```
$ jar tf ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-assembly/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/spark-assembly-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-hadoop1.0.4.jar | grep .class
org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
```

To see number of `class`es,

```
jar tvf launcher/target/usergrid-launcher-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep .class | wc -l
61079
```

Comment: this was exactly what I needed, even if the question owner needed a code-based solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

This is a hack I'm using:

You can use `java`'s autocomplete like this:

```
java -cp path_to.jar <Tab>
```

This will give you a list of classes available to pass as the starting class. Of course, trying to use one that has no main file will not do anything, but you can see what `java` thinks the classes inside the `.jar` are called.

Answer (score 8):

You can try:

```
jar tvf jarfile.jar
```

This will be helpful only if your jar is executable i.e. in manifest you have defined some class as main class

Comment: Add some specific example on an example jar to your answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the

```
jar tf example.jar
```

Answer (score 4):

Below command will list the content of a **jar** file.

command :- `unzip -l jarfilename.jar`.

sample o/p :-

`Archive:  hello-world.jar
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
     43161  10-18-2017 15:44   hello-world/com/ami/so/search/So.class
     20531  10-18-2017 15:44   hello-world/com/ami/so/util/SoUtil.class
---------                     -------
    63692                     2 files`

According to manual of `unzip`

> -l     list archive files (short format).  The names, uncompressed file sizes and modification dates and times of the specified files are
>   printed, along with totals  for  all
>                 files  specified.   If UnZip was compiled with OS2_EAS defined, the -l option also lists columns for the sizes of stored OS/2
>   extended attributes (EAs) and OS/2 access
>                 control lists (ACLs).  In addition, the zipfile comment and individual file comments (if any) are displayed.  If a file was
>   archived from  a  single-case  file  system
>                 (for example, the old MS-DOS FAT file system) and the -L option was given, the filename is converted to lowercase and is
>   prefixed with a caret (^).

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 4):

Mac OS:
On Terminal:

```
vim <your jar location>

after jar gets opened, press / and pass your class name and hit enter
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
unzip -v /your/jar.jar
```

This will be helpful only if your jar is executable i.e. in manifest you have defined some class as main class

Answer (score 2):

Use this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for VARIABLE in *.jar
do
   jar -tf $VARIABLE |grep "\.class"|awk -v arch=$VARIABLE '{print arch ":" $4}'|sed 's/\//./g'|sed 's/\.\.//g'|sed 's/\.class//g'
done
```

this will list the classes inside jars in your directory in the form:

```
file1.jar:fullyqualifiedclassName
file1.jar:fullyqualifiedclassName
file1.jar:fullyqualifiedclassName
file1.jar:fullyqualifiedclassName
file2.jar:fullyqualifiedclassName
file2.jar:fullyqualifiedclassName
file2.jar:fullyqualifiedclassName
```

Sample output:

```
commons-io.jar:org.apache.commons.io.ByteOrderMark
commons-io.jar:org.apache.commons.io.Charsets
commons-io.jar:org.apache.commons.io.comparator.AbstractFileComparator
commons-io.jar:org.apache.commons.io.comparator.CompositeFileComparator
commons-io.jar:org.apache.commons.io.comparator.DefaultFileComparator
commons-io.jar:org.apache.commons.io.comparator.DirectoryFileComparator
commons-io.jar:org.apache.commons.io.comparator.ExtensionFileComparator
commons-io.jar:org.apache.commons.io.comparator.LastModifiedFileComparator
```

In windows you can use powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.jar |
ForEach-Object{
    $filename = $_.Name
    Write-Host $filename
    $classes = jar -tf $_.Name |Select-String -Pattern '.class' -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch
    ForEach($line in $classes) {
       write-host $filename":"(($line -replace "\.class", "") -replace "/", ".")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Description OF Solution** : Eclipse IDE can be used for this by creating a sample java project and add all jars in the Project Build path

**STEPS below**:

1. Create a sample Eclipse Java project.
2. All all the jars you have in its Build Path
3. CTRL+SHIFT+T and Type the full class name .
4. Results will be displayed in the window with all the jars having that class. See attached picture . 
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

windows cmd: 
This would work if you have all te jars in the same directory and execute the below command

```
for /r %i in (*) do ( jar tvf %i | find /I "search_string")
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I started working on this basic problem, the problem is that I needed to look at a package path for java enumerations and create a list of instances implementing a specific interface.  The package was in a jar file dependency as part of a spring boot application.

The first problem, getting a list of classes from the jar file.  spring boot made that fairly simple once I found the solution.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(classLoader);
Resource[] resources = new Resource[0];
try {
    resources = resolver.getResources("classpath:com/enumeration/*.class");
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("failed to load Enumeration classes using classpath: >{}< {}", "classpath:com/enumeration/*.class", e.toString());
}
```

Once I found the list of classes, instantiating the enumerations worked with the following code.  This is outside the scope of the initial question but exemplifies traversing a list of class files in a package.

```
List<Enum> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Resource resource : resources) {
    String classPathName = ((ClassPathResource) resource).getPath().replaceAll("/", ".").replaceAll(".class", "");
    Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(classPathName);
    Class<Enum> aClass1 = (Class<Enum>) aClass;
    Enum anEnum = Enum.valueOf(aClass1, aClass1.getEnumConstants()[0].name());
    list.add(anEnum);
}
```