# Blindly get Java class names?

Tags: java, class, jvm, names

Is there a way to collect java class names(as Strings) on the jvm system path when you know nothing about the context of the classes? I have seen a few similar questions, but all require at least knowing the package names.

I have looked at Java [Interface Instrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getAllLoadedClasses%28%29), but unless I'm misreading things, it appears to only relate to programs actively running on the JVM.

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am writing a program that manipulates a separate program using javassist. I can do so by simply stating class names to the manipulator(i.e. "HelloWorld" will return the HelloWorld.java class). I am hoping to expand this so that the manipulator can have a gui that lists all the classes of the separate program so the user does not have to know the class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the class path jars and directories via:

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

and then you can list all the classes in the jars as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15720973/597657) shows.