# How to view all contents of all jars in a given directory?

Tags: java, jar

Maybe I'm just having a brain dead day but, **what is the easiest/best way to get the contents of all jars in a given directory**?

I'm running into a classpath/loader conflict so I want a way to get a list of the entire contents of all the jars to find my problem.  I know that there are some tools that will help with this but, for the life of me, I can't think of any of them.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**
For reference, here's what I've been doing (this is broken up for readability but I just do it all on one line as a shell script):

```
OUTFILE=/tmp/allClasses.txt ; 
touch $OUTFILE; 
for file in *.jar; 
do echo " === $file " >> $OUTFILE; 
jar -tf $file >> $OUTFILE; 
done;
```

This seems to work pretty well but it just feels clunky.

---

For reference, here's what I've been doing:
`touch /tmp/allClasses.txt ; for file in *.jar ; do echo " === $file " >> /tmp/allClasses.txt ; jar -tf $file >> /tmp/allClasses.txt ; done;`

This seems to work pretty well but it just feels clunky.

Comment: Take a look at [`ZipInputStream#getNextEntry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html#getNextEntry()).

Comment: [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15720973/597657).

Comment: Thanks for moving that up Steve. Editing to improve the script in case anyone else want's to use it.

Answer (score 2):

open the jar-file as an archive with Winrar or 7zip

Comment: I'm aware that you can open a jar with zip tools but I'm not aware of one that allows you to easily extract information about the contents of a large number of files at once.

Answer (score 1):

`jar xf jar-file` extracts the contents of a JAR file.

Comment: It does, yes. The OP has been edited to show what I'm doing now (using something similar to this) but I'm looking for a more efficient way to do it on a large number of files.

Answer (score 0):

A jar file is just a zip file (compressed or not), you can even change its extension from jar to zip and unzip it

Answer (score 0):

[`zipinfo`](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zipinfo.html) can list the contents of several zip (or JAR) files at once:

```
zipinfo \*.jar
```

the trick is to escape the `*` so `zipinfo` itself expands the wildcard rather than the shell expanding it and then passing the expanded list to `zipinfo` (which doesn't work as zipinfo expects the first argument to be the archive to look in and the subsequent arguments to be entry paths *within* that archive).