# How do I list all the methods of all the beans and its methods available in a package in java

Tags: java

I am using some client jars which provides the Bean framework of my application in my automation framework. I want to list out all the packages and classes from each packages available in the jar files. Is there a straight forward way in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enumerate all classes in a package and add them to a List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176527/how-can-i-enumerate-all-classes-in-a-package-and-add-them-to-a-list)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720822/how-to-get-names-of-classes-inside-a-jar-file

Answer (score 1):

In order to see the classes inside a jar file .. I would recommend a approach that first requires to execute a command.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar tvf file.jar > file.txt");
```

Now just read from this file using java api's and filter out the strings ending with .class that will denote the class files.

For alternative approaches also read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720822/how-to-get-names-of-classes-inside-a-jar-file)