# Factory method overloading

Tags: java, overloading

I have a list of subclasses which are all instance of Super class.
My goal is to create a factory, which will return different result depending on subclass.

```
public class SuperClass {
    ...
}

public class SubClass1 extends SuperClass {
    ...
}

public class SubClass2 extends SuperClass {
    ...
}

public class Factory {
    public static getInstance(SubClass1 item) {
        return new EditText();
    }

    public static getInstance(SubClass2 item) {
        return new CheckBox();
    }
}

public class Generator {
    public Generator() {
        List<SuperClass> list = getList();

        for (SuperClass item : list) {
            Factory.getInstance(item);
        }
    }

    List<SuperClass> getList() {
        ...
    }
}

new Generator();
```

This code will fail during compilation as it will require *getInstance(SuperClass item)* overloading, but if I add it then it always will be called.

Is there a way to do this without touching SuperClass, SubClass1, SubClass2?

UPD. In order to clarify what I want to archive here is the original code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.cos.COSArray;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageTree;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotation;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDCheckbox;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDRadioButton;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField;


public class Page {
    private View view;
    private Context context;
    private PDDocument file;

    public Page(Context _context, View _view, PDDocument _document) {
        view = _view;
        context = _context;
        document = _document;

        renderFields();
    }

    private void renderFields() {
        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
        RelativeLayout ll = view.findViewById(R.id.pageFields);
        ll.removeAllViews();

        PDPageTree pageTree = docCatalog.getPages();
        PDPage page = pageTree.get(pageIndex);

        PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
        List<PDField> fields = acroForm.getFields();

        for (PDField field : fields) {
            String fieldName = field.getFullyQualifiedName();
            COSDictionary fieldDict = field.getCOSObject();

            COSArray fieldAreaArray = (COSArray) fieldDict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.RECT);
            PDRectangle mediaBox = new PDRectangle(fieldAreaArray);

            int fieldColor = Color.argb(180, 220, 228, 254);
            // Factory
            View fieldView = FieldFactory.getViewFromPDField(context, field);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams fieldLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int) (mediaBox.getWidth() * posRatio),
                (int) (mediaBox.getHeight() * posRatio)
            );
            fieldLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            fieldLayoutParams.leftMargin = (int) (left * posRatio);
            fieldLayoutParams.topMargin = (int) (top * posRatio);
            fieldView.setBackgroundColor(fieldColor);
            fieldView.setLayoutParams(fieldLayoutParams);

            ll.addView(fieldView, fieldLayoutParams);
        }
    }
}

...

public class FieldFactory {
    public static View getViewFromPDField(Context context, PDTextField field) {
        return new EditText(context);
    }

    public static View getViewFromPDField(Context context, PDCheckbox field) {
        return new CheckBox(context);
    }

    public static View getViewFromPDField(Context context, PDRadioButton field) {
        return new RadioButton(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `item` is a `SubClass3`?

Comment: public static getInstance(...) - does this even compile? What about the return type?

Comment: How about using generics ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291714/how-to-implement-factory-pattern-with-generics-in-java

Comment: The [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) allows you to do this in an object-oriented way, but that involves touching `SuperClass` and all subclasses.  Otherwise it means in `Generator()` testing the type with `instanceof` with a bunch of `if` conditions and casts.

Comment: @JamesB I'm sorry, I haven't tried to compile this exact code, but my code is similar.

Comment: @rgettman I was thinking about Visitor, but I cannot modify SuperClass and subclasses as they are provided by third-party library.

Comment: You are moving towards instanceof?

Comment: @SirajK so far it looks like the only way, but maybe someone have any other idea.

Comment: Could you update your example code to be clearer for *why* you want to do this?

Comment: @Vitruvius Added original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no clean way to do that because during compile time we do not know which method to invoke. To do that you can use `instanceof` keyword or use reflection.

Assuming that your model looks more or less like below:

```
class SuperClass {
    //...
}

class SubClass1 extends SuperClass {
    //...
}

class SubClass2 extends SuperClass {
    //...
}

class Context {
    //...
}

abstract class View {
    private final Context context;

    public View(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}

class TextBox extends View {

    public TextBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}

class CheckBox extends View {

    public CheckBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

You can implement factory like below:

```
class FieldFactory {
    static Map<Class<? extends SuperClass>, Class<? extends View>> fieldEditorMap = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        fieldEditorMap.put(SubClass1.class, TextBox.class);
        fieldEditorMap.put(SubClass2.class, CheckBox.class);
    }

    public static View getViewFromPDField(Context context, SuperClass field) {
        Class<? extends View> editorClass = fieldEditorMap.get(field.getClass());
        try {
            return editorClass.getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(context);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can not create view for " + field.getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<SuperClass> fields = Arrays.asList(new SubClass1(), new SubClass2(), new SubClass1());
        for (SuperClass field : fields) {
            System.out.println(FieldFactory.getViewFromPDField(new Context(), field));
        }
    }
}
```

Above prints:

```
TextBox
CheckBox
TextBox
```

Of course this is just an example, you should implement it better using some Reflection libraries or utils. We assume that each `View` implementation has given constructor, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead make `SuperClass` abstract and add a new instance method that does what you are looking for, with each subclass overriding it with its different behavior:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    public abstract View getView(Context context);
}
public class SubClass1 extends SuperClass {
    @Override
    public View getView(Context context) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked [Michał Ziober](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51591/micha%C5%82-ziober)'s solution, and would like to expend it using [java generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

The reasoning behind using generics is to have a single, versatile implementation which can later be used for a multitude of tasks.

I've revised the original solution into a generic one. The Factory must now be instantiated, since it is generic and instantiation provides us with a specific factory for specific classes of our choice.

I've used my [online java compiler](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler) of choice in order to compile and run the following code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {

    static class SuperClass {
        //tagging
    }

    static class SubClass1 extends SuperClass {
        //
    }

    static class SubClass2 extends SuperClass {
        //...
    }

    static class Context {
        //...
    }

    static abstract class View {
        private final Context context;

        public View(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getClass().getSimpleName();
        }
    }

    static class TextBox extends View {

        public TextBox(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
    }

    static class CheckBox extends View {

        public CheckBox(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
    }
    static class Pair<P0,P1> {
        public P0 p0;
        public P1 p1;
        public Pair(P0 p0, P1 p1) {
            this.p0 = p0;
            this.p1 = p1;
        }
    }
    static class FieldFactory<T extends SuperClass, P extends View> {
        Map<Class<T>, Class<P>> fieldEditorMap = new HashMap<>();

        public FieldFactory(List<Pair<Class<T>, Class<P>>> boundClassMapping){

            boundClassMapping.stream().forEach(pair -> fieldEditorMap.put(pair.p0,pair.p1));
        }

        public P getViewFromPDField(Context context, T field) {
            Class<P> editorClass = fieldEditorMap.get(field.getClass());
            try {
                return editorClass.getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(context);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can not create view for " + field.getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Pair<Class<? extends SuperClass>, Class<? extends View>>> mapping = new ArrayList<>();
        mapping.add(new Pair<Class<? extends SuperClass>, Class<? extends View>>(SubClass1.class, TextBox.class));
        mapping.add(new Pair<Class<? extends SuperClass>, Class<? extends View>>(SubClass2.class, CheckBox.class));
        FieldFactory ff = new FieldFactory(mapping);
        List<SuperClass> fields = Arrays.asList(new SubClass1(), new SubClass2(), new SubClass1());
        for (SuperClass field : fields) {
            System.out.println(ff.getViewFromPDField(new Context(), field));
        }
    }
}
```

As for the outputs :

```
TextBox
CheckBox
TextBox
```

Comment: I just presented an idea to use reflection. I did not want to complicate it by adding generics but it is a good idea, I think.

Comment: @MichałZiober : Thanks buddy! (feel free to upvote if you are so inclined)