# List of packages from JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to get list of all packages that a Javafx application has.Is there function for doing this ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720822/how-to-get-names-of-classes-inside-a-jar-file . From the fully qualified class names you should be able to get to the packages easily...

Comment: you want to know all the package name in a jar file?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto My JavaFX Program have alot of packages(folders) I want to get list of all packages automatically by code.

Comment: your application is in a jar file or in a folder?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto My app is a simple JavaFX app,I want to get list of my app package at runtime for making dynamic tabpane.