# How to read classes from a jar

Tags: java, jar, decompiling, decompiler

I am trying to read classes from a jar.
So I started by extracting the files under my jar, I am using JAD decompiler.
The decompiler works, for example I have written

```
System.out.println()
```

And I have tried to open the class System and it shows the implementation of the class.
When trying to read the .class under my jar, I have tried to put the .class under a package, but I can not see the .class under the package, so I have tried to open it like this : File>Open File.., I get the error :
The Class File Viewer cannot handle the given input ('org.eclipse.ui.ide.FileStoreEditorInput').

How can I see my .class?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720822/how-to-get-names-of-classes-inside-a-jar-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open any .class files with [Intellij IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/idea/)

Comment: Why minus? In addition: the Class File Viewer can only open class files which are on the Java
build path of a project.

Comment: Please see the following link, they describe your issue: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/452483/